# Vim has Erroneous Behavior on paste?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

This honestly might be a bug. But sometimes when I am pasting into vim (on insert mode, using CMD+V), it just pastes some partial output of what I had copied and does extra things like deleting existing content and/or exiting insert mode.

This appears to happen only some of the time, and is usually restored by exiting my ssh session & restarting the connection. Is this a bug are there workarounds or am I somehow using vim incorrectly?

Comment: Did you read `:help 'paste'` (and possibly down to `:help 'pastetoggle'`)?

Comment: No, but this seems to only happen after a while like corrupt cache. Are you saying its supposed to paste nonsense?

Comment: The way I see it, you can *read* it or argue with me about what you think it says.

Comment: Haha ok, fair enough.

Comment: Don't bother, D. Ben Knoble put it in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste using OS-level pastes, like Command-V, you should use the `paste` option or `pastetoggle` to "protect" the pasted keystrokes. Modern terminals that support bracketed paste can actually handle this somewhat automatically *as long as Vim is able to read the relevant terminfo entries and set `t_PS` and `t_PE` correctly*.

Why "protect" the paste? Well, if the paste contained <kbd>Esc</kbd>`ggdG`, it would be kind of annoying to interpret that as typed characters, wouldn't it? Protecting the paste with the `paste` option forces Vim to interpret a little differently:

```
    Put Vim in Paste mode.  This is useful if you want to cut or copy
    some text from one window and paste it in Vim.  This will avoid
    unexpected effects.
    Setting this option is useful when using Vim in a terminal, where Vim
    cannot distinguish between typed text and pasted text.  In the GUI, Vim
    knows about pasting and will mostly do the right thing without 'paste'
    being set.  The same is true for a terminal where Vim handles the
    mouse clicks itself.
    This option is reset when starting the GUI.  Thus if you set it in
    your .vimrc it will work in a terminal, but not in the GUI.  Setting
    'paste' in the GUI has side effects: e.g., the Paste toolbar button
    will no longer work in Insert mode, because it uses a mapping.
    When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
        - mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled
        - abbreviations are disabled
        - 'autoindent' is reset
        - 'expandtab' is reset
        - 'hkmap' is reset
        - 'revins' is reset
        - 'ruler' is reset
        - 'showmatch' is reset
        - 'smarttab' is reset
        - 'softtabstop' is set to 0
        - 'textwidth' is set to 0
        - 'wrapmargin' is set to 0
        - 'varsofttabstop' is made empty
    These options keep their value, but their effect is disabled:
        - 'cindent'
        - 'formatoptions' is used like it is empty
        - 'indentexpr'
        - 'lisp'
        - 'smartindent'
```

---

(Actually, if the paste contained something that looked like an escape keystroke, Vim might not be able to handle that correctly without bracketed paste.)